# Can I pause/freeze an AWS EC2 dedicated host to reduce costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm playing with the AWS EC2 Mac instance.

To save costs, I stop the EC2 instance when it's not needed, but my dedicated host is still running and generating costs.

Is there a way to stop a dedicated host similar to EC2?

I could release a dedicated host but for the mac1 instance, it charges me for 24h in the beginning so it's not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you cannot "pause" an EC2 dedicated host.**

---

A dedicated host (on-demand) only stops charging you when it is released.

As per [the user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-dedicated-hosts-work.html#dedicated-hosts-releasing):

> **After you release a Dedicated Host**, you can't reuse the same host or host ID again, and **you are no longer charged On-Demand billing rates for it**.

Or [the FAQs](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/ec2/dedicated-hosts/faqs/):

> **You will pay the On-Demand rate for every hour the host is active** in your account

---

You could also take a look at **moving the EC2 instance to a shared tenancy, releasing the host, and then starting it back up when needed** if this is possible. You can refer to this [AWS Premium Support guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-shared-tenancy-dedicated-host/) for steps on how to do this but I still wouldn't recommend it (though it is a valid way to "pause" the dedicated host).

Just try your best to use the 24hrs!

Comment: I planned to use AWS EC2 instance in build application stage in my CI/CD. I wanted to start my EC2 at the beginning and stop at the end of build process. Is there something that you can recommend for my use case?

Comment: Why are you using dedicated hosts for building? Go with a regular EC2 instance - and even then, do you have to use an EC2 instance for building? What are you running your CI/CD pipeline on? Is an EC2 instance required?

Comment: I use EC2 mac instance because I need to build iOS app

Comment: The reason why I used dedicated host is that you cannot use mac1 instance type without dedicated host. It's only supported tenancy type

Comment: Ah yes you're right - again: what are you running your pipeline on? There may be better options.

Comment: Gitlab, I read that they want to support mac build at the beginning of 2022 - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/284838. Mac builds are available for beta testing which does not satisfy me, since my solution will be used commercially

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238862/discussion-between-unknown123-and-ermiya-eskandary).